# How do I disable javelin jsp-recompiler in weblogic 10.3?

Tags: weblogic

How do I disable weblogic's javelin recompiler? It seems to be using some version of JDK5 source level, and I believe that this can be disabled in weblogic 10 in favor of regular JDK6.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible. Switch to Tomcat before your brain explodes.